# How to dissallow certain characters in a UITextview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a uitextview that is editable but there are certain characters I would like to be disallowed from being typed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a delegate to the UITextView, and implementing the following method in the delegate:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

In the body just write some code that scans through the input text to see if you find the characters you want to filter, if you see them return NO, otherwise return YES.

Comment: This not enough. When the user pastes some text, the forbidden character may be *in* the pasted text. In that case, you may not want to reject the paste altogether. You might prefer deleting (or replacing) the forbidden characters. I am still struggling to achieve that in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not that simple, because `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText:` is not necessarilly called with one-character strings. It is for keyboard input, but it isn't when pasting, or when using speech recognition to enter text.

So what do you want to do if the user pastes (or dictates) a string that contains forbidden characters? You might want to let all valid text go through and only delete (or replace) unwanted characters.

The incorrect idea would be to fix the text in the `textViewDidChange:` delegate routine. While this seems to work, it somehow prevents speech input from working in the `UITextView`.

The correct idea is to implement `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText:` with full filtering. Here is a sample implementation that filters out newlines:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{   
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder]; // dismiss keyboard
        return NO;
    }

    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];   // replace by spaces

    NSString *fullText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    textView.text = fullText;

    return NO;
}
```

Note that it dismisses the keyboard when the user strikes the enter key. But not quite perfectly: it will also dismiss the keyboard when the user pastes a single newline character. This might be a problem, but this should happen only rarely.